# MySQL: Copy from 1 table to another not overwriting existing?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

1. tableOriginal
2. tableBackup

They have exactly the same structure.

I want a SQL statement I can run anytime of the day, that will copy all the rows from tableOriginal to tableBackup WITHOUT overwriting items in tableBackup. Basically, this command must synchronize tableBackup with tableOriginal.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tableBackup(SELECT * FROM tableOriginal)
```

As long as there is no issue with primary keys being updated or replaced with new incoming data this should not create an issue for you. However as you already know, backup table will have more data after your command since it did not delete previous data it had

Comment: Although, if a primary key or other unique constraints exist, then it might become a bit more tricky.

Comment: I only want to add the data that is not yet in the new backup table... no changes, so I believe this will work? And it won't copy the data twice, right?

Comment: Yes it will copy only once unless u run this query twice. But one catch is that if you dont delete date from your original table then next time you run this query again then it will bakup all of it again even the ones you backed up already. So you have to either empty backup like suggested in the answer below or later remove all the copied data from  original

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you **delete first** all the data in **tableBackup**, then **INSERT** the data in **tableOriginal** to **tableBackup**

```
DELETE FROM tableBackup
INSERT INTO tableBackup(SELECT * FROM tableOriginal)
```

Why do we need to delete first?
Because if we're going to insert unique data into the tableBackup,
next time we insert it will not execute, because we will insert/add some data that is already been there..

Hope you get what I'm trying to say.

Comment: This seems the best option. If you just insert you will only get new records. What if an old record is updated? What if the structure changes btw? Use; CREATE TABLE tableBackup SELECT * FROM tableBackup

Comment: This suggestion nullifies the very basic request which OP made `not overwriting existing(data)? `. Please also note that the word `unique` was not used by OP

Comment: actually we all know, there many ways to solve his problem.. basically if the OP just wants to backup his original Database... simply inserting would just be fine, but it will populate the tableBackup same data if he doesn't have a uniqe column.. which is not really good to happen.. and I think, deleting first before insert would be the easiest way.. just to avoid conflicts in unique data..